# Reselect library is returning a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I'm trying to use the reselect library for the first time and I feel like I'm following the examples to a T, but obviously I'm missing something.  When I try to use it, the mapStateToProps thinks I'm returning a function rather than an object which I'm exepecting.

Can someone tell me what step I'm missing?  I've looked over this a few times already and can't seem to pinpoint what I'm missing.  Thank you.

// initial redux state

```
data: {
  pageDict: {
    id1: { name: 'somePage1', ... }, id2: { name: 'somePage2', ... }
  }
}
```

// selectors.js

```
const getPageDict = state => state.data.pageDict;

export const getPage = (state, props) => createSelector(
  [getPageDict],
  (pageDict) => {
    return pageDict[props.pageId];
  }
);
```

// MyComponent.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    page1: getPage(state, ownProps),  // this causes an error as it thinks I'm returning a function
    page2: state.data.pageDict[ownProps.pageId]  // this works fine
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getPage` function is currently defined as "a function that takes `(state, props)`, and returns a new selector".  That's the wrong syntax and approach.  Instead, you should be defining `getPage` as "a selector function generated by `createSelector` that accepts `(state, props)` as arguments":

```js
const getPageDict = state => state.data.pageDict;
const getPropsId = (state, props) => props.pageId;

const getPage = createSelector(
    [getPageDict, getPropsId],
    (pageDict, pageId) => pageDict[props.pageId]
);
```

That will make your usage in `mapState` correct.

Having said that, note that a simple object key lookup like this doesn't really even benefit from use of Reselect's `createSelector` here, as there's no real memoization going on.  This could be as simple as:

```js
const getPage = (state, props) => state.data.pageDict[props.pageId];
```

See my post [Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/) for more details on how and why to use Reselect.

Comment: good answer with a helpful explanation as well and link.  tyvm